# Display PrintDialog in a console application c#

Tags: c#, printing, console-application

i am working on a c# console application but want to know :
if it is possible to show the *PrintDialog* in a **console** application ?

Comment: Yes, of course it's possible. Haven't you tried it?

Comment: It's simpler if you use the `System.Windows.Forms.PrintDialog` version. -- Note that the Dialog it will be parented to the desktop, not the Console Window.

Comment: ...unless you assign the Console Window Handle to a NativeWindow, then cast the NativeWindow object to `IWin32Window` and pass it to the `ShowDialog()` method. Now you have a Console-Modal Dialog :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to print something from your console application and want PrintDialog, you can use the below code.

```
PrintDialog printDlg = new PrintDialog();  
PrintDocument printDoc = new PrintDocument();  
printDoc.DocumentName = "Print Document";  
printDlg.Document = printDoc;  
printDlg.AllowSelection = true;  
printDlg.AllowSomePages = true;  
//Call ShowDialog  
if (printDlg.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK) printDoc.Print();
```

Comment: thank for trying to help me but it does not show the dialog

Comment: i have tried but i does not show the dialog.

Comment: Try this one, it is working on my machine.

Comment: thank you the dialog is shown but the document  that i want to print is in the specific folder, what can i do ?

Comment: for print document, just see example mentioned on this [Page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.printing.printdocument?view=net-5.0)

Comment: it is not possible to print pdf usign StreamReader, it possible to print txt files et docx. because pdf file is a binary file.

Comment: I was not aware that you are using PDF, let me have a look once again.

Comment: Here is the solution of printing a pdf document but here you cant use PrintDialog. Have a look [LINK](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/2b42ce70-66be-4fbe-a135-b6e503f49b79/printdialog-with-microsoft-print-to-pdf?forum=netfxbcl)

Comment: thank you very for your help but my problem is to show the dialog.